# Upload data as image to Wordpress using Wordpress API

Tags: python, wordpress, google-cloud-functions, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to take the URL of an image, download it, and then upload it to wordpress using the Wordpress API. Here is my code:

```
def upload_media(self, media_url):
    # Get the last path component
    filename = media_url.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(media_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
        upload_url = self.__upload_media_url()
        headers = { "Content-Disposition": f'attachment; filename={filename}'}
        files = { 'file': image.tobytes() }
        request = requests.post(upload_url, auth=(self.username, self.password), files=files, headers=headers)
        return request
```

Each time this fails with the following error:

`{'code': 'rest_upload_unknown_error', 'message': 'Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.', 'data': {'status': 500}}`

Originally I had the following code, which worked on my local machine. However, because I want to run this on Google Cloud Functions, I do not have access to the file system. Thus the process of open/close will not work.

```
def upload_media(self, media_url):
    # Get the last path component
    filename = media_url.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(media_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        upload_url = self.__upload_media_url()
        headers = { "Content-Disposition": f'attachment; filename={filename}'}
        files = { 'file': open(filename, 'rb')}
        request = requests.post(upload_url, auth=(self.username, self.password), files=files, headers=headers)
        os.remove(filename)
        return request
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What exactly is the type of image you're trying to upload - PNG? JPG? something else? Anyway, this is not a Python problem, you need to configure the Wordpress instance to allow uploading files of this type, see https://wpforms.com/docs/how-to-allow-additional-file-upload-types/

Comment: They’re png/jpg images which are already supported by default. If I download the file and save it to disk then use open, everything works fine. Is there a way to simulate that same sort of thing without actually saving the file?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes `image.tobytes()` produces RAW image data, not PNG or JPG compressed data  - so, what you're trying to upload is **not** one of the allowed types.

Just drop this line:

```
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

and then use:

```
files = { 'file':  BytesIO(response.content) }
```

I believe this should fix your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that yields the same 500 error as before. Wordpress seems to require  file extension which this collection of bytes does not have :(

Comment: file extension (`.jpg` or `.png`) should be part of the `Content-Disposition:` header, and it seems you're actually putting it there - unless your `media_url` does not end in one of those extensions?

Comment: The Content-Dispostion for the request reads: `{'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=img-2611001-m.jpg'}`

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I had to make 2 changes to my original function.

1. Add a `Content-type: image/jpeg`
2. Use `data=` instead of `file=`

Here is the working function which requires no open/closing of any files:

```
def upload_media(self, media_url):
    # Get the last path component
    filename = media_url.split('/')[-1]
    response = requests.get(media_url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        upload_url = self.__upload_media_url()
        headers = { "Content-Disposition": f"attachment; filename={filename}" , "Content-Type": "image/jpeg" } 
        return requests.post(upload_url, auth=(self.username, self.password), headers=headers, data=response.content)
```